# An integral involving hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

As part of a research project, I have arrived at the following integral which I need to evaluate:
$$
I_n(r) = \frac{\gamma_+(r)}{\sqrt{5}} \int dr \frac{r \gamma_-(r)}{(2+r^2)^2} P_n(r)  - \frac{\gamma_-(r)}{\sqrt{5}} \int dr \frac{r \gamma_+(r)}{(2+r^2)^2} P_n(r) 
$$
where
$$
\gamma_\pm(r) = r^{\pm \sqrt{5}-1} \,_2 F_1 \left( \frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} , 1 \pm \sqrt{5} , - \frac{r^2}{2} \right)
$$
and $P_n(r)$ is a source function whose exact form I already know. For example:
$$
P_0(r) = \frac{-2(1+2r^2)}{(2+r^2)^2} , \qquad P_1(r) = - \frac{4+4r^2+25r^4}{4(2+r^2)^3} , \qquad P_2(r) = \frac{128+188r^2+542r^4+165 r^6}{16(2+r^2)^4} .
$$
I have tried evaluating this in Mathematica and that fails! To go around this, I tried evaluating the integral with a series expansion -- Taylor expand the integrands $\frac{r \gamma_\pm(r)}{(2+r^2)^2} P_n(r) $ around $r=0$ perform the integral and then resum the end result. This worked beautifully for me for the first two cases and I found (up to integration constants which I don't care about)
$$
I_0(r) = - \frac{1}{8(2+r^2)}, \qquad I_1(r) = - \frac{1+2r^2}{16(2+r^2)^2} .
$$
The same procedure fails for $n=2$ since I am unable to resum the final result. What I get is
$$
I_2(r) = \frac{1}{16}+\frac{33 r^2}{512}-\frac{243 r^4}{5120}+\frac{2287 r^6}{56320}-\frac{64221 r^8}{2140160}+\frac{1016715 r^{10}}{49651712}-\frac{54081877 r^{12}}{4071440384}+\frac{232816473 r^{14}}{27991152640}-\frac{80660100021 r^{16}}{15898974699520}+\frac{34324313347417 r^{18}}{11320069986058240}-\frac{879985309187031 r^{20}}{493555051392139264}+\frac{6080353048255923
   r^{22}}{5877791975670022144}-\frac{1081421076370723949 r^{24}}{1822115512457706864640}+O\left(r^{26}\right)
$$
**Any help in resumming this would be appreciated!**

**More generally though, I would like advice on how to simplify $I_n(r)$.** Given the relatively simple form of the final answer for $I_0$ and $I_1$ despite the involvement of the complicated hypergeometrics suggests to me that there might be another way to approach this integral which I am missing -- perhaps using some of the various properties of the hypergeometric functions.

**ASIDE**: Within the same project, I also end up with another similar sort of integral
$$
K_n(y) = \frac{\rho_-(y)}{2\sqrt{5}} \int dy \frac{y^3 \rho_+(y)}{(y^2-1)^2} Q_n(y) - \frac{\rho_+(y)}{2\sqrt{5}} \int dy \frac{y^3 \rho_-(y)}{(y^2-1)^2} Q_n(y) 
$$
where
$$
\rho_\pm(y) = (y^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2} ( \pm \sqrt{5}+1)} \,_2 F_1 \left( \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{5\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} ; 1 \pm \sqrt{5} ; \frac{1}{1-y^2} \right)
$$
and $Q_n(y)$ is a known source function. Any suggestions on evaluating this integral (for $y>1$) would be equally appreciated!

Comment: Is there any helpful geometrical or other background context you can supply for your question?