# Differential Equation involving hypergeometrics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

My earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360617/an-integral-involving-hypergeometric-functions?noredirect=1#comment9106866_4360617) did not get answered so I'm presenting a related question with the hope that the answer to this will help me figure out the other one myself. I have come across the following differential equation which I would like to solve:
$$
4(2+r^2)f(r) - r ( 6 + r^2) f'(r) - r^2 ( 2 + r^2 ) f''(r) = P(r) =  \frac{r^2}{4(2+r^2)}
$$
I also know the exact solution to this
\begin{align}
f(r) &= c_1 \gamma_+(r) + c_2 \gamma_-(r) + \frac{\gamma_+(r)}{\sqrt{5}} \int dr \frac{r \gamma_-(r)}{(2+r^2)^2} P(r) - \frac{\gamma_-(r)}{\sqrt{5}} \int dr \frac{r \gamma_+(r)}{(2+r^2)^2} P(r)  
\end{align}
where
$$
\gamma_\pm(r) = r^{\sqrt{5}-1} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(-3\pm\sqrt{5}\right),\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{5}\right);1\pm\sqrt{5};-\frac{r^2}{2}\right)
$$
The issue now is that I am unable to evaluate the integral in the solution and I don't think there is a nice solution anyway [I'd be happy if anyone thinks otherwise!]

My final goal is to find the Taylor expansions of $f(r)$ near $r=0$ and $r=\infty$ respectively. Is there any way to extract these expansions without actually doing the integrals? Of course I know we can determine the expansions by first expanding the integrand and then doing the integrals. However, this process is ambiguous up to the integration constants. How would I go about fixing these ambiguities?

Comment: A general solution of the homogeneous ODE about $r = 0$ is given by the Frobenius method. If we already know there is a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous ODE which is a power series, we can substitute $f_0 = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k r^k$ into the ODE to obtain a recurrence relation for $a_k$:
$$a_{k + 2} = -\frac
 {4 (k^2 + k - 4) a_k + k (k - 4) a_{k - 2}}
 {4 (k^2 + 6 k + 4)}, \\
a_0 = a_1 = a_3 = 0, \, a_2 = -\frac 1 {64}.$$